# What does the extra "e" mean in some names?

Tags: meaning

Many times, I saw an "e" on some names. For example:

> blackthorne

Is this only for decoration, or is the extra "e" from old english? Or maybe spelling for certain cultures?

Comment: Yes, all of the above.  It's often added to "invented" names to make them seem higher-class.  Sometimes the extra "e" is just an accident of history -- when the spelling was "hardened" vs what the style was at that moment, sometimes the extra "e" is due to it being "borrowed" from French or some other language.  (Net:  Aside from its possible effect on pronunciation the extra "e" is meaningless.)

Comment: So when a business calls itself **Ye Olde Shoppe** it is just to attract the rubes?

Comment: @GEdgar Exactly. It looks French, which suggests high class, but the French never spelled it like that.

Comment: @GEdgar: Not quite. "Ye" and "olde" are real words widely used in old English, but "shoppe" isn't.

Comment: @user21820 Ok. I know these are widely used. But excluding them, some names have it for decoration or accident of history, as Hot Licks said

Comment: There is a shopping center near here named "Shoppes on Maine".  There's nothing named "Maine" within 500 miles (and there's not even a "Main Street" in town), and the "shoppes" are your regular haphazard mix of shopping center boxes (including such high-class store as Lowes and Target).  I always call the place "shoppies on mainy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all of the above. It's often added to "invented" names to make them seem higher-class. Sometimes the extra "e" is just an accident of history -- when the spelling was "hardened" vs what the style was at that moment, sometimes the extra "e" is due to it being "borrowed" from French or some other language. (Net: Aside from its possible effect on pronunciation the extra "e" is meaningless.)

Answer (score 0):

I have been asked on several occasions whether the I have an E or Not and one explanation was if I had an e I was Catholic similarly a friend was told by his Father that the family did not have an e because 'We are not Catholic'.  In Eire the side of the family who were Unionist dropped the O and the side that were Republican kept it.  So there seem to be political and religious reasons for the addition and removal of letters.  Could the removal of the e in England be traced to Protestantism?

Comment: Despite the common pronuncitation of "low" (meaning below normal), the "rules" of English pronunciation would have the "O" pronounced as a "short O" (as in "hop").  Adding the "E" tells those observing the "rules" that it's a "long O".

Comment: That Julie provided no scholastic citations might mean she should have Posted a Comment, rather than an Answer.

That doesn't change the fact, she provided a very plausible answer to the Question… it just means getting to the root of that might well take tomes.